# Interspacing Meditation Practice

Tags: meditation-practicalities

I have been practising breathing meditation for some time. Now, I feel compassion meditation would benefit me more. I was thinking of practising 30 min of *each* every day.

**Would such interspaced practise (one session breathing, one session compassion, etc.) be beneficial, or discouraged?**

In other words, **is it better to stick to the same practice on the long term?**

Comment: It is said that Brahmavihara leads to jhana, but I can't find canonical evidence of it. In most Buddhism, compassion practices don't lead to factual acts of compassion, but merely to creating a mood. I find that breathing practice leads to compassion which I can act on.

Comment: @brothereric I'm not trying to complain, and thank you for posting, but FYI [When my answer is short, shall I post it as a comment instead?](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1589/254) Generally a "good answer" is based on something -- perhaps a reference to literature, and/or personal experience -- so I think what you posted might be better posted as an answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 1):

While it is sometimes said that Brahmavihara leads to jhana, but I can't find canonical evidence of it. In most Buddhism, compassion practices don't lead to factual acts of compassion, but merely to creating a mind filled with compassion and loving kindness. While I think compassion practices are a good idea, translating the mentally felt compassion is more of a problem. Personally, I find that breathing practice leads to compassion which I can act on. (Chris edit as you like)

Here is a study concerning mindfulness meditation not making a difference in terms of prompting compassionate actions:
https://digest.bps.org.uk/2017/05/17/mindfulness-training-does-not-foster-empathy-and-can-even-make-narcissists-worse/

Here is an article saying more empathy isn't what we need:
https://www.fastcompany.com/40483014/actually-we-dont-need-more-empathy